# JS button event with redirect (Sonata Admin)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, redirect

I'm using Sonata Admin for my project and I have a SweetAlert 2 on `$('button[type="submit"]')` event.

The problem is that initially I'm using `preventDefault()` to keep form alive, then I'm trying to submit form with `$(form).submit()` but I'm redirected to the same EDIT page even if I click on "Update & Close" page.

FYI: Sonata has 2 possibilities:'Update' & 'Update and close'. First one is updating entity and redirect you to the same page, the other one, is updating entity and redirecting you to listing page.

```
$('button[type="submit"]').click(function (e) {
    var currentStatus = $('#' + adminUniqueId + '_status option:selected').val();
    var exitDate = $('#' + adminUniqueId + '_exitDate').val().trim();
    var form = $(this).parents('form');
    var nextPage = $(this).attr('name');

    loanId = parseInt(loanId);

    // Modal operations
    if((currentStatus === closedStatus || exitDate !== '') && loanId !== 0) {
        if (outstandingBalance > 0) {
            e.preventDefault(); // Stop action until we find a response.

            swal({
                title: 'Current outstanding principal balance is $' + numberFormatter.format(outstandingBalance) + '. How much do you want to write off ?',
                input: 'text',
                width: '600px',
                inputClass: 'money-mask',
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonText: 'Close this loan',
                showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
                preConfirm: function (amount) {
                    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                        var convertedAmount = getValueFromFormattedNumber(amount);

                        if (isNaN(convertedAmount)) {
                            reject('Please write an amount.')
                        } else if (convertedAmount < 0 || convertedAmount > outstandingBalance) {
                            reject('The write-off amount is greater than the outstanding principal balance.')
                        } else {
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: setLoanTransactionRoute,
                                data: {
                                    loanId: loanId,
                                    outstandingBalance: outstandingBalance,
                                    amountToWriteOff: convertedAmount
                                },
                                success: function (data) {
                                    if (true === data.success) {
                                        $('#' + adminUniqueId + '_status').val(closedStatus).change();
                                        setTimeout($(form).submit(), 500);

                                        resolve();

                                    } else {
                                        reject('We found an error: ' + data.message + '.')
                                    }
                                },
                                error: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                                    reject("Something went wrong and we couldn't add this transaction. Please check if you have a write-off and/or repayment loan category.")
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    })
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you show us your code you've made so far?

Comment: @eeya I edited first post.

Comment: As given in your question, Your objective here are as follows : (When user click the `Update` button, It will redirect to the `same edit page`. When user click the `Update and close` button will redirect to the `listing page` instead). Is this correct?

Comment: @eeya, Yes, it's true and that's happens if I don't use `e.preventDefault()`.

Answer (score 0):

> When user click the [Update] button, It will redirect to the same edit page and when user click the [Update and close button] will redirect to the listing page instead

As documented by `swal` plugin, You can call the deferred callback `then` by the time `swal` `preConfirm` function callback:

https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/

Here's a given reference code:

**Note:** I've place a [id] attribute for this given form and some additional conditions as well

```js
$('#frm-submit input[type="submit"]').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var aValidSubmitValues = ['Update', 'Update and Close'];
    var sButtonValue = $(this).val();
    if ($.inArray(sButtonValue, aValidSubmitValues) < 0) {
        return false;
    }

    var convertedAmount = '123.00';
    var outstandingBalance = '200.00';
    
    swal({
        title: 'Current outstanding principal balance is $100.00 How much do you want to write off ?',
        input: 'text',
        width: '600px',
        inputClass: 'money-mask',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: 'Close this loan',
        showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
        preConfirm: function(amount) {
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                if (isNaN(convertedAmount)) {
                    reject('Please write an amount.')
                } else if (convertedAmount < 0 || convertedAmount > outstandingBalance) {
                    reject('The write-off amount is greater than the outstanding principal balance.')
                } else {
                     // Your given ajax code up until the resolve callback parameter
                     // Your $.ajax() here until resolve
                     resolve();
                }

            });
        }

    }).then(function(response) {
        console.log('You have click the ' + sButtonValue + ' button');
        if (sButtonValue === 'Update') {
             console.log('Reload the page');
             // location.reload()
        } else {
             console.log('Go to a certain listing page');
             // location.href = '/list-of-transaction-page';
        }
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/6.11.5/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <form id="frm-submit">
        <input type="submit" value="Update" />
        <input type="submit" value="Update and Close" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Hope this will guide you well

Comment: Give me one more day to try this and I'll see if it works. If it does, I'll mark this as answer.